# How to sort a timestamp in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, timestamp

I have a column with timestamps in a pandas data frame.
The format of the timestamp is HH:MM:SS.MSMS (e.g. 12:28:20.33).

I want to sort them from the smallest to the largest, considering all values in the timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a timestamp column, you just sort it as you sort any other column. e.g.:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['time_col'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
sorted_df = df.sort_values(by='timestamp')
```